# Error in R equivalence comparison: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, runtime-error

I'm having troube with an error in my script.

I have a data frame with the `death_year column` (with values between 2000 and 2013) and I want to fill the cell of another column (year_X - being X a value between 2000 and 2013) with the value of 1 if the `death_year == year_X`.

The outut would be something like this:

```
death_year  year_2000 year_2001 year_2002
[1]  2000           1        0         0
[2]  2002           0        0         1
[3]  2009           0        0         0
```

That's my script:

```
a<-vector("numeric")

for(i in data$death_year){
  for(j in 2000:2013){
    if(i == j){
      for(c in 1:length(data)){
          data[c,paste( 'year', j, sep="" )]==1
    }
  }
}

Error in if (i == j) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Type `data$death_year` in your console.  What do you get as output?

Comment: I get a vector with years and NAs

Comment: The NA's are your issue.  You cannot use `==` on NA's

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem indeed

Comment: np.  Incidentally, notice that it was the same answer as given by @BrianDiggs in the question linked here ;)